# MySQL connection error that I have never seen

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

New mysql error:

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.9]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand' at line 1
```

Ive never seen this error before and dont know what its relating to?

```
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=fakepass;"))
    {
        // ODBC command and transaction objects
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

        // tell the command to use our connection
        command.Connection = connection;

        try
        {
            // open the connection
            connection.Open();

            // start the transaction
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            // TODO: Build a SQL INSERT statement
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "')", connection);

            // run the insert using a non query call
            command.CommandText = cmd.ToString();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            /* now we want to make a second call to MYSQL to get the new index 
               value it created for the primary key.  This is called using scalar so it will
                return the value of the SQL  statement.  We convert that to an int for later use.*/
            command.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            Label10.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
            // the name id doesnt not exist in the current context

            // Commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label10.Text = ": " + ex.Message;

            try
            {
                // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
    using (var conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=fakepass;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var tx = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES (@Email, @FirstName, @SecondName, @DOB, @Location, @Aboutme, @username, @password)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", TextBox3.Text);

                // TODO: might require a parsing if the column is of type date in SQL
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TextBox4.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", TextBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aboutme", TextBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox7.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox8.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//error on this line
            }

            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                Label10.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
            }

            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

{"ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized."}

Comment: I noticed the line of code which holds your SQL syntax is rather long. You can place an `@` sign before the quotation mark to enable the string to span multiple lines. Also it looks like your opening yourself up to SQL injection building your query like that.

Comment: If this is an externally-accessible server, you're also opening yourself up to attack by posting your SQL username and password like that.

Answer (score 8):

Why are you still using the buggy ODBC to connect to MySql when there is an [ADO.NET connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)? Also what is this horrible string concatenation when forming your query?:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "')", connection);
```

Haven't you heard of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [parametrized queries](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) which allow to avoid it?

All I can say is that if you use the `+` sign when writing a SQL query it's like taking a gun and shooting right at your foot (or head depending on the scenario, but in all cases you are shooting at yourself, basically a suicidal behavior).

So, here's the proper way to do things:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var tx = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES (@Email, @FirstName, @SecondName, @DOB, @Location, @Aboutme, @username, @password)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", TextBox3.Text);

            // TODO: might require a parsing if the column is of type date in SQL
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TextBox4.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aboutme", TextBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox7.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox8.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            Label10.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
        }

        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Also please name those textboxes appropriately. The poor guy that's gonna maintain this code might emit screams of despair.

Comment: Also, I found the reuse of the command quite dangerous, I'd recommend to instantiate a new Command for a completely new task

Comment: @Garrith Graham, from what I can see in your code you are using an `OdbcConnection` which is fundamentally different than a `MySqlConnection`.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Comment: In debug its on the cmd.executenonquery line after the paramarters

Comment: LOL@ Also please name those textboxes appropriately. The poor guy that's gonna maintain this code might emit screams of despair

Comment: Is select last_insert_id() going to return the right value being processed before the Commit?  I use procedures so I'm just asking.

Comment: i think select last_insert_id() is something specific to mysql not sure how it works but what ive read all it does is return the last auto increment primary key inserted in the syntax before hand.