# Why can odbc not do two querys?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mysql, sql

Looking for another method to my previous posts:
[MySql and inserting last ID problem remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542999/mysql-and-inserting-last-id-problem-remains)

and

[MySQL connection error that I have never seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544261/new-mysql-connection-error-ive-never-seen)

Im trying to come up with other ways to get the UserID after an insert statement but im falling short.

I refuse to beilieve some one wrote the odbc without thinking "wait a minute what if some one wants to execute two querys" I mean its been around for ages?

Or maybe its not so much two querys but getting the last inserted query back, this may be a short fall from c#...

My only other option would be to place all my textboxes in some kind of container along with the button and when the button is clicked I use my first insert statement and set that container visibile = false. and have a second container below it which was initialy invisible but after the first button click set it to visible with the new fileupload control and new button for a new insert, but that wont solve the issue of how to get the userid after its been inserted without a session? And there is no session without being authenticated.

I tagged javascript in this as Im not sure if there is anything a second code could help with?

Comment: just a thought, but is there a way to get the highest number in a coloum? as its auto increment I think I would still be safe with something like that. Rather than last insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the [MySQL ODBC connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html):

> `FLAG_MULTI_STATEMENTS` **Allow multiple statements** Enables support for batched statements. This option was added in Connector/ODBC 3.51.18.

So make sure you install Connector version 3.51.18 or newer, then enable the multi-statement flag before running your batch by specifying `option=67108864` in the connection string   .

Comment: think im running a lower version of odbc and forgot about the options on connection strings

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for the LAST_INSERT_ID() function.  Check out the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Hey Bob, yeah those have been tried and dont work each time generating a sql syntax error on the select row_count or select last_insert_id. It seems odbc cannot do two querys no matter which way you try.

Comment: You will notice im my previous posts that this was attempted from the links provided in this question